# prototype object/method code - not displaying on cosole

Tags: javascript, function, methods, console, prototype

So this code is for my javascript class, so it isn't exactly essential for a website per se, but I am stuck nonetheless. So I am trying to make a code that, when I call a certain name and a method (name, type1, type2, height or weight), I get the answer that I provided in my code. I am getting undefined, but when looking at my instructor's demo, it works.

I hope I am not missing something really simple. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
 var Pokemon = function Pokemon(name , type1 , type2 , height , weight) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type1 = type1;
  this.type2 = type2;
  this.height = height;
  this.weight = weight;
}

Pokemon.prototype.whichPoke = function whichPoke() {
  console.log("Hey, I am " + this.name);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichType1 = function whichType1() {
  console.log("Hey, I am " + this.type1);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichType2 = function whichType2() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.type2);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichHeight = function whichHeight() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.height + " inches tall");
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichWeight = function whichWeight() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.weight + " pounds")
}

var Horsea = new Pokemon({
  name: "Horsea",
  type1: "Water",
  type2: "none",
  height: "16",
  weight: "17.6"
})
var Seadra = new Pokemon({
  name: "Seadra",
  type1: "Water",
  type2: "none",
  height: "47",
  weight: "55.1"
})
var Kingdra = new Pokemon({
  name: "Kingdra",
  type1: "Water",
  type2: "Dragon",
  Height: "71",
  Weight: "335.1"
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 var Pokemon = function Pokemon(name , type1 , type2 , height , weight) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type1 = type1;
  this.type2 = type2;
  this.height = height;
  this.weight = weight;
}

Pokemon.prototype.whichPoke = function whichPoke() {
  console.log("Hey, I am " + this.name);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichType1 = function whichType1() {
  console.log("Hey, I am " + this.type1);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichType2 = function whichType2() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.type2);
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichHeight = function whichHeight() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.height + " inches tall");
}
Pokemon.prototype.whichWeight = function whichWeight() {
  console.log ("Hey, I am " + this.weight + " pounds")
}

var Horsea = new Pokemon("Horsea", "Water", "none", "16", "17.6");
var Seadra = new Pokemon("Seadra", "Water", "none", "47", "55.1");
var Kingdra = new Pokemon("Kingdra", "Water", "Dragon", "71", "335.1");
```

Comment: The parameter {...} you passed to create Pokemon object is ONE object rather than 5 data. It is recognised as one parameter - 'name' rather than as 5 parameters. So the rest parameters type1, type2, height, weight will be undefined.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/sl4rj9/9

Here we go, this is my issue. I don't get any specific information, just this. haha

Comment: I am embarrassed. My code actually works, I just didn't put my () after my function call.

Comment: never feel bad about any type of bugs :)